# if or statement xml and java console output

Tags: java, xml, if-statement

Below is an extract from my code

```
Document doc = loadXMLFromString(httpPostJava());
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*"); 
int bookCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
    String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

    if (nodeName.equals("assd") ||nodeName.equals("eventy")) {
        System.out.println(("\t"+nodeName+"\t" element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
    }
```

The problem i have is that i want the output from the "assd" node and the "eventy" node to be side by side in the console output. Currently it is being printed underneath the "assd" node and this because the the if statement is finding the "assd" node printing out the data and the loop runs again now outputting to the line below. I am fairly new to Java well 6 months of exposure.

Output i am hoping should like

```
assd    eventy
data    data1
```

Following on from Glorfindel's suggestion this is the output i am getting in the console:

```
    assd                eventy
frail
    GYMR    
grail
    KRYM
```

The output i am looking for is:

```
assd                eventy

GYMR                frail
KRYM                grail
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print `assd` and `eventy` only once, you need to do so *outside* the for-loop. And it seems that eventy comes before assd, so you need additional tricks:

```
System.out.println("\tassd\teventy");
String eventy = null;
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
    String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

    if (nodeName.equals("assd")) {
        System.out.println("\t" + element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue() + "\t" + eventy);

    } else if (nodeName.equals("eventy")) {
        eventy = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
    } 
}
```

<sub>This assumes the `assd` and `eventy` elements occur alternating in the XML document.</sub>

Comment: @ Glorfindel Thanks for the help with the headers, however the output is not coming out as expected still - i am going to update my question in a few moments with the output i get

Comment: Updated my answer - might contain some syntax errors because I have only mobile phone access right now. I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: @ Glorfindel I dont quite understand how this works but it does, where you declare   + eventy why does it not fail since eventy is declared before eventy is given a value. ie. eventy is only declared in the else if statement..It is set at null until the else if statement runs please explain...

Comment: on debugging it runs from if (nodeName.equals("assd")) { ....to..... } else if (nodeName.equals("eventy")) {.....why?

Comment: Yes, `eventy` is `null` for a while. But because of the structure of your XML, it will always have a value set *before* it is used in a `println` statement.

Comment: @ Glorfindel i have to be honest this is something new to me on how i understand if else statements with XML.

Comment: Not any different than in normal loops. Really, a debugger is very useful here. Check the value of `nodeName` each time, and compare it to your source XML.

Comment: @ Glorfindel i will definitely do that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize

```
 StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
```

before you use for loop.

In for loop, you need

```
st.append("\t"+nodeName+"\t" element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()));
```

Then after the for loop, you can:

```
System.out.stringln(st.toString());
```